# How to use multi select dropdown list asp net

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I´ve just download the multi select dropdown list but I´m not able to give the properly design. I dont know where to put the links and script in my page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="3" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Guava" Value="4" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="5" />
    </asp:ListBox>


    <!-- Include Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery: -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>


    <!-- Initialize the plugin: -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
        });
    </script>



</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change id from `example-getting-started` to `ListBox1`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#ListBox1').multiselect();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I changed it but I´m still having the same output like a simple list box

Comment: No. I think is the source:  href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" I dont have that path in my project. I installed Bootstrap multi select with nugget package, Any ideas how to use it properly?

Comment: Did you try CDN url for testing? https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: probably needs `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the ListBox